# Using fail_on_empty in Airflow V2

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, snowflake-connector

I am using Airflow V2 for my ETL. I am using the SnowflakeSqlSensor in this ETL. In Airflow V1, I was using the parameter `"fail_on_empty=True"` within the SnowflakeSqlSensor. When I use the same parameter in Airflow V2, I get an error saying `"Invalid argument"`. In the Airflow V2 documentation, we see that this is a valid argument. Are there any additional parameters that need to be used in association with `fail_on_empty` in Airflow V2? Also what is the default value of this parameter in Airflow V2?